# How can I abort an Akka TCP connection before it connects?

Tags: scala, akka

I am trying to connect to a TCP socket in an akka actor:

```
IO(Tcp)(context.system) ! Tcp.Connect(new InetSocketAddress(url,port)
```

I will of course get a message if the connection succeeds or fails, as described in the akka documentation.

However, sometimes what I need is to cancel the request before it either succeeds or fails. something like a Tcp.disconnect counterpart for the Tcp.connect call above, that I can call if the user cancels the request before connect has a chance to succeed or fail.

Does anyone know of a way to do that?

Comment: How would you know that you want to abort?  Would you want to give up after `x` milliseconds (a timeout)?

Comment: Imagine that it tries to connect on a click of a button by the user. if the user closes the browser, or clicks on another button which needs connection to another TCP endpoint, I will know that I need to abort this connection. makes sense?

Comment: It looks like there's a method `TcpMessage.abort()` that might be of interest to you: http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.4/#akka.io.TcpMessage$  I've never used TCP explicitly in Akka, but you might find what you need there.

Comment: Actually, it looks like `TcpMessage` is a Java API (`"The Java API for generating TCP commands is available at TcpMessage."`), but I think `Tcp.Abort` might be what you want: http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.4/#akka.io.Tcp$  My guess is you send it like any other command, since it says "object
Abort extends CloseCommand" and "An abort operation will not flush pending writes and will issue a TCP ABORT command to the O/S kernel which should result in a TCP_RST packet being sent to the peer."